# Taper a geonodes curve to center of curve & adjustable via group input?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, geometry, splines

I've created and resampled a curve and want to smoothly taper it to the center.

I'm able to do ***exactly*** what I need using the spline parameter node and a float curve, but the problem is that I'm unable to expose these settings to a group input.

I'm seeking an alternative method that provides similar control via group input. For my purposes, I believe this would be 8 input values (listed towards bottom).

[image]

The ideal solution (see image below), if it's possible, would allow independent radius settings for the start and endpoints of the curve as well as the three "taper control points"  and also provide independent <-------> positioning controls along the curve for the 3 "taper points".

I think the following **group input example** reflects the 8 necessary input settings from the float curve example above:

- Startpoint radius: (value)
- Taper A (nearest startpoint) radius: (value)
- Taper A (nearest startpoint) location along curve: [factor slider]
- Taper B (near center of curve) radius: (value)
- Taper B (near center of curve) location along curve: [factor slider]
- Taper C (nearest endpoint) radius: (value)
- Taper C (nearest endpoint) location along curve: [factor slider]
- Endpoint radius: (value)

[image: ![enter image description here]

*Please note, the float curve applies its settings to all curve geometry and I am seeking a solution that does the same. My original post only included an image showing one curve and not multiple curves. I mistakenly cropped them out thinking they were not necessary for my example.*

[image]

Comment: Instead, could you not build a curve in 3DViewport of 5 points align along X between 0 and 1, encoding factor of points A/B/C and radius ? Then just add this curve to the group input list ? You can edit it as you are doing with the float curve, but in 3DViewport instead of inside GN editor. You can extract factors and radii from this curve.